# Aggregating netCDF files with R

Tags: r, aggregation, netcdf

Looking for an aggregation of two netCDF file in order to have only one file.
In the first file I have data from 01/01/1995 00h00 to 01/01/1999 00h00 and in the second file  it is from 01/01/1999 00h00 to 01/01/2000 00h00 (so one date in common). For this step this is the same variable into the two files.

After that I want to aggregate severals netCDF files having the same period but different variables. The final file should regroupe 4 variables from 01/01/1995 00h00 to 01/01/2000 00h00.

I don't know how I can do that with R, I tried with 'ncdf' but it is just a creation...

Tkx!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`cdo` toolset](https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo) for this. `cdo` has the `cat` option which you can use to concatenate NetCDF files, which is what you need. Even if this does not work, `cdo` is bound to have an option of doing what you need. See the [`cdo` documentation](https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Cdo#Documentation) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! There is another package too: nco. Seems to be hard with R

Comment: Hard in what sense? You can call `cdo` from within R using `system`.

Comment: I didn't know! I saw that I can call cdo with the command system('/usr/bin/cdo') and what should I add to use 'merge' for example?

Comment: I recommend you read the documentation of `cdo` first, if you have specific questions after that, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: Ok I am  already using cdo with the console (ubuntu) so I think I will continue that way.

Comment: If my answers solves your problem, you can mark it as such by clicking on the green tick mark to the left of my question. This shows that your question has been solved.